# iText 7.7.1.16 - cannot open pdf document

Tags: itext7

I used itextsharp 5 for years, now I am testing iText 7 (v7.7.1.16.). I have a very strange issue with a simple code:

```
Dim src As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\test.pdf"
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(src)
Dim pdfDoc As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(reader)
```

the pdfdocument instance fails with error "Cannot open document" iText.Kernel.PdfException.

**The file exists** and the current user has access to read it (Copying the complete path during debug, I have got a working path: pdf opens in adobe acrobat). I tried to move file in another location, but the issue still occurs. I tried also with different pdf files.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: I examined inner exception: unable to load assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' but I added the reference to my project...

Comment: With that little information... most likely either the path is wrong, the file is broken, or you don't have permissions to access the file.

Comment: I examined inner exception: unable to load assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' but I added the reference to my project...

Comment: Ok, that points to an issue that is caused by some project setup or build problem. Your question currently only addresses people with iText 7 knowledge. You should edit it so that it addresses people with [tag:visual-studio] project setup or [tag:.net] build knowledge.

Comment: The issue happens in each file system access. I am trying trial version and iText returns the same issue when I load license key. So, I suppose that there is some incompatibility with my environment.

Comment: You mentioned that you examined the inner exception and it cannot load an assembly and you say you have it as a reference. Did you add it manually? If yes, then which other references you added? You may not have added all of them. Have you tried to explore the inner exceptions even further?